# Algebras without Nontrivial Subalgebras

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let us define an algebra to be a pair $(A, \mathcal{F})$, where $A$ is a set and $\mathcal{F}$ is a collection of finitary functions on $A$. Some common algebras include groups and rings.

I have left undergraduate and graduate-level algebras for a while now, but I am looking for examples of algebras without nontrivial subalgebras and I can't seem to think of any. Trying to manufacture one seems to be quite daunting, too. I did a little googling also and it did not help.

Can you refresh my memory or give me a pathological example? The simpler $\mathcal{F}$ is the better, but I am only interested in examples with infinite $A$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}$ is a simple example of a ring with no nontrivial subrings. The point is that the signature of this algebra includes both a constant term for the multiplicative identity $1$, and an operation $+$ with the property that it's generated by the constant term under repeated applications of the operation.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks!

Comment: Now, what happens if we don't include those constants? In such a case, the "ring" has an abundance of "subrings". Any example with the property I am interested in?

Comment: @Benjamin: if the signature doesn't include any constant terms then there's an empty subalgebra. If that counts as "trivial" for you, then consider the pair consisting of the infinite set $\mathbb{Z}$ and the pair of unary operations $f, g : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ given by $f(x) = x + 1$ and $g(x) = x - 1$.

Comment: Thank you, Yuan! I will consider if the example you give works for what I am working on.